# How to cross-reference reactions in chemmacros/chapter?

Tags: chemmacros

I changed the labeling format that also the chapter number is included (R 0.1). When I cross reference to the reaction only the number (1) and not the whole label with chapter number is used. How can I get the same format/label also for the cross reference?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={all}}
\chemsetup[reactions]{
    before-tag = R \thechapter.,
    tag-open = ( ,
    tag-close = )
}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
  A + B &-> C "\label{test1}" \\
  X + Y + Z &-> XX "\label{test2}"
\end{reactions}

In reaction \ref{test1} and \ref{test2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand\thereaction{R~\thechapter.\arabic{reaction}}` instead of the before-tag key?

Comment: Thank you, that is all what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see the same for math equations. This is because the tag is what is put around the counter number *in equations*.

`\the<counter` is what represents how the counter number is actually to be printed, *everywhere*:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\renewtagform{default}{[}{]}
\usetagform{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  1 \neq 2 \label{foo}
\end{equation}

\ref{foo} % not [1] but 1

\renewtagform{default}{}{}
\renewcommand\theequation{[\arabic{equation}]}

\begin{equation}
  3=3 \label{bar}
\end{equation}

\ref{bar} % [2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's completely analoguous with `chemmacros` reactions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{reactions}
\renewtagform{reaction}{[}{]}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
  CH4 \label{foo}
\end{reaction}

\ref{foo} % not [1] but 1

\renewtagform{reaction}{}{}
\renewcommand\thereaction{[\arabic{reaction}]}

\begin{reaction}
  H2O \label{bar}
\end{reaction}

\ref{bar} % [2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

`chemmacros` options are really just wrappers around `mathtools`' `\renewtagform`.